# Learning about DC voltage

Tags: power, dc, amperage, watts, volts

I have a step up booster that increases my 36 V battery to 50.1 V. If I plug it into my 48 V battery which charges to 54 V it still reads 54 V on the multimeter. I'm wondering why. Could it be increasing the current and not the voltage?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering why am I thought is could it be increasing the amps and not the volts?

If a power converter increases the volts, the amps have to drop. The product of the two - the power (in Watts) - must remain constant, or will decrease (due to losses), but can never increase.

> if I plug it into my 48 volt battery which charges to 54 volts it still reads 54 volts on the multimeter

The step-up module is designed to step the input voltage up to 50V. You gave it a voltage *higher* than 50V on the input, so the module has nothing to do, and just passes the input voltage to the output. A step-up module can **only** step the voltage up, it can't step it down.

If you'd want to have a constant 50V on the output using a high-efficiency power converter, you'll want a **buck-boost** module. Those can step the voltage either up or down, depending on what the input-output voltage relationship is at a given time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, a step-up voltage booster (just a boost converter) is designed to increase the voltage from its input to its output. However, the behavior you're observing might be explained by a few possibilities:

1. Your booster might have an upper voltage limit near or below 54 volts. If the output voltage is set (or naturally tends) to be 50.1 volts when powered by a 36-volt battery, and if the boost converter's maximum achievable output is near 54 volts (or less), then when you connect a 48-volt battery that charges to 54 volts, the booster simply cannot increase the voltage any further. The booster might be operating at its maximum capacity.
2. Most boost converters have feedback mechanisms to regulate their output voltage. If the output voltage of the booster is approaching or is above its set point, the booster may reduce or entirely cease its boosting operation.
3. Some boost converters may not regulate well without a significant load attached. If you're measuring the output with a multimeter and there's no significant load connected to the booster's output, it might just show the input voltage, especially if the input voltage is already near or above the booster's set output voltage.
4. The voltage booster will primarily affect the voltage, not the amperage (current). However, due to the conservation of energy, when you boost the voltage, the current capacity (in amperes) of the output will be less than the current capacity of the input, assuming 100% efficiency. In real-world scenarios, due to losses in the converter, the efficiency will be less than 100%. But the primary function of the voltage booster is not to increase current; it's to increase voltage.
5. Ensure that your multimeter is accurate and calibrated. A faulty or low-quality multimeter might give misleading readings.

To get a clearer picture of what's going on:

- Make sure your boost converter is rated for the voltages and currents you're working with.
- Test the booster with a load attached to see if the behavior changes.
- Double-check all connections and settings, especially if the booster has adjustable output settings.

If you are still puzzled after considering the above possibilities, there may be other factors or issues at play specific to your booster or setup. Lets us know.